# Using signalR to display online users in real time, good idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to put a count of how many users are online and make it update in real time as users join so everyone knows how many users are online.  I am wondering if this would be bad by design because as more and more users come on it would have to send a message to possibly thousands-millions of clients.  Now, I understand you can always scale to handle the load, but is that even a good idea to do that?  will it be light on the server or will it consume a lot of resources to have to update the amount of online users every time someone joins?

Comment: Apologies in advance for bluntness: That seems like a huge amount of work for something that IMO has no real tangible benefit to end users. Aren't there better features for you to work on?

Comment: Whenever you are wondering if using SignalR could be a solution to your problem, you should ask yourself if you really have a problem in the first place. ;) #joke

Comment: Do you actually have millions of simultaneous clients? Or even thousands? Solve the problem in front of you first - get a realistic count and design for that scale. If your usage blows up, that's a good problem to have.

Comment: Sounds like this could easily be solved on the client. Especially if it knows who the users are in the session. Let the browser count the number of users.

Answer (score 3):

Absent a compelling business or use case, no, I don't think it's a good idea to display a real time user count to possibly millions of users, and I certainly don't think it's a good idea to *communicate* that real time user count continuously to all of them.

Have an internal user count number you update once a minute or so; show that number on page load.

Comment: What's your reasoning for this?

Comment: Unless the number of online users is a critically important piece of information to all of the users, then why bother? We're talking about creating huge amounts of server load to display a pretty meaningless number to potentially millions of different people. What is the strategic business case for this, other than "it's cool"?